# if condition is not executed (cs50 recover)

Tags: c, cs50

I've been trying to find the bug for several hours now. Writes a segmentation error. Help pls ;)

Task page: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2024/psets/4/recover

The assignment is to recover 50 JPEG files that were deleted from a memory card. We are instructed to check the first 4 bytes of each 512 byte pass of fread to indicate the start of a JPEG file and to write it to a new file. Once it reaches another 4 bytes that match, we are suppose to close the previous file and write to a new one until reaching EOF (the data from the memory card is provided to us in a file called card.raw).

In my decision if (buffer[0] == 0xff, etc. is not executed, after while immediately comes else and because, as i understand, a segmentation (core dumped) error is written.

That is, the code is compiled and after its execution the following is displayed:
while executed
else executed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

But the condition itself is written correctly, because I changed it to those written by other people. It looks like the data from the card is not being written to buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 512
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Accept a single command-line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover FILE\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the memory card
    FILE *card = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (card == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
    int number_file = 0;
    char filename[8];
    FILE *img = NULL;
    bool this_first_jpeg = true;

    // While there's still data left to read from the memory card
    while(fread(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, card) == 1)
    {
        printf("while executed\n");
        // if start of new JPEG
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] >= 0xe0 && buffer[3] <= 0xef))
        {
            printf("if executed\n");
            if (this_first_jpeg == true)
            {
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", number_file++);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, img);
                this_first_jpeg = false;
            }
            else
            {
                fclose(img);
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", number_file++);
                img = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, img);
            }
        }

        // if already found JPEG
        else
        {
            printf("else executed\n");
            fwrite(buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, img);
        }
    }

    fclose(card);
    fclose(img);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to take pieces of other people's code and it still doesn't work. But the other code completely works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: If you're getting a segfault, a debugger will stop exactly where that's happening.

Comment: The first data block is not guaranteed to be a header block. If it isn't (as suggested by the `if` condition not passing), the `else` code block will write to a file that hasn't been opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you should open the memory card file in binary mode: `FILE *card = fopen(argv[1], "rb");`
- same for the image files: `img = fopen(filename, "wb");`
- if you do not have a JPEG signature (the `else` branch), you always write the block to `img`, which is `NULL` when you start the loop.  Calling `fwrite(buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, img)` with a null `FILE` pointer has undefined behavior, possibly a segmentation fault as observed.
- after the loop, you always close `img`: `fclose(img)` will cause undefined behavior if `img` is `NULL`, ie if no image file was found.  You must test if `img` is `NULL`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 512
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Accept a single command-line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover FILE\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the memory card
    FILE *card = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (card == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    BYTE buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
    int number_file = 0;
    char filename[8];
    FILE *img = NULL;

    // While there's still data left to read from the memory card
    while (fread(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, card) == 1)
    {
        // if start of new JPEG
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff
        &&  (buffer[3] >= 0xe0 && buffer[3] <= 0xef))
        {
            if (img != NULL)
            {
                /* close current image */
                fclose(img);
            }
            snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "%03i.jpg", number_file++);
            img = fopen(filename, "wb");
            if (img == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not open image file %s: %s\n",
                        filename, strerror(errno));
                fclose(card);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        if (img != NULL) {
            /* if current JPEG open, write the block */
            fwrite(buffer, BLOCK_SIZE, 1, img);
        }
    }

    fclose(card);
    if (img != NULL) {
        fclose(img);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just some thoughts: The questions looks like some kind of "homework" to me. _Here is a modified version_ most likely leads to some copy and paste, probably without even reflecting in detail about how the issues you mentioned could be solved (without copying your solution).

Comment: @MarkusSafar The code in question is quite literally homework, for a very popular online course called [tag:cs50]. It is trivial to find partial or entire solutions to this problem set online, including [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcs50%5D+recover). There is no particular onus on this answer to champion academic honesty; whether someone wants to copy & paste their way through this course, or learn directly from a working example is on them.

Comment: Thank you. The code works. But, to be honest, I still don’t understand why mine doesn’t. I know that there are problems there, but at least it should output "if executed" as I see it. I just want to understand my code, and not copy someone else’s.

Comment: @Pupseg didn't you read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77742899/if-condition-is-not-executed-cs50-recover#comment137057370_77742899)? Why wouldn't the first block be a header block? Because you are recovering a possible 50 files from a broken card.

Comment: @Pupseg: as I stated in the answer, `img` is initially null and unless you find a signature on the first block, which is very unlikely, you will call `printf("while executed\n")`, then `printf("else executed\n");` and finally `fwrite(buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, img)` which will crash.  The previous output might never get to the IDE if `stdout` is fully buffered.  You could call `fflush(stdout)` after each call to `printf` to ensure proper output to the IDE and investigate if my explanation holds.

Comment: Time is 05:42 and I finally understood.  First block is not a header block. Thank you all very much!